# Jquery catcomplete search not working

Tags: jquery, json, jsp, autocomplete

I am trying to use JQuery Category Catcomplete to create a search input for my website that will search through results that are in another file located at "/file.jsp". The result of file.jsp is a JSON string (file contents are listed below). The problem is that the autocomplete results increase when I write in the input text.
For example when I write 00 in searchDealer the results are 3, when I write 0000 the results are 6, and so. 
The autocomplete results are always all visible.

Here is my code:

```
$(function( request, response) {
var tally = new Object();
var idx;
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
        var self = this,currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
            if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "(<span id='autocomplete_"+item.category+"'></span>)</li>");
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            if(currentCategory!=''){
                tally[currentCategory] = (tally[currentCategory]==undefined) ? 1 : tally[currentCategory]+1;}
            self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
        for(category in tally){
            $('#autocomplete_'+category).html(tally[category]);
        };
    }
});


 $("#searchDealer").catcomplete({
     source: "file.jsp",
     minLength: 2,
     delay: 0,

             select: function(event, ui) {
                 alert('Select');
             }

         });
});
```

Here is the json response of `file.jsp`:

```
[
 {"label":"000123 dealer S.r.l.","category":"Concessionari"},
 {"label":"000456 AUTOMOTORS abc SNC","category":"Concessionari"},
 {"label":"000789 AbcAUTO SRL","category":"Concessionari"}
]
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved. The problem was in source:

```
  $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "file.jsp",
              dataType: "json",
              error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
              {

                if(jqXHR.status == 401)
                {
                    alert(expiredSessionMessage);
                    $('#logoutLink').find('a.linkCommon').click();
                }   
              },              
              success: function(json){
                  $("#searchDealer").catcomplete({
                  source: json



                    });

            }



        });
```